# How to use svn-client on RHEL5 after the server disabled SSLv3?

Tags: svn, openssl, rhel-5, rhel-6

To deal with the recently-discovered POODLE vulnerability in SSLv3, we disabled the old protocol on our servers -- including the Subversion repository server.

This broke the svn-clients on our RHEL5 machines -- they now report the following error:

`svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.example.net/foo/trunk/': SSL negotiation failed: Secure connection truncated (https://svn.example.net)`.

The svn version is 1.6.11. The same version on RHEL6 is fine, so one could think, the difference lies in the openssl-libraries.

But Apache running on the same RHEL5-box as the svn-client uses the same libraries and is serving its own SSL-traffic without a hitch (over TLSv1).

How do I make svn-client work without the svn-server supporting SSLv3?

*Update*: Looking closer at `ldd`'s output, I see that `svn` links with GNUTLS on RHEL6, but OpenSSL on RHEL5, which may account for the difference. I still don't understand, why Apache using OpenSSL on the same RHEL5 system has no problem offering TLSv1, however.

Comment: Did you already update the openssl on the RHEL5 box?  Did that include updating or recompiling svn?

Comment: Correct. Installing the mere week-old openssl RPMs from RedHat (`openssl-0.9.8e-31.el5_11`) did not solve the problem. Nor did recompiling subversion from source...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this workaround https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1234843.

svn-client <-- supports SSLv3 --> local stunnel <-- no SSLv3 / automatic fall back to TLS --> SVN server

> Some components do not provide configuration parameters that allow
>   SSLv3 to be disabled. Currently, the following components are known to
>   fall into this category:
>
> OpenLDAP
>
> cups
>
> It is possible to disable SSLv3 for these components by
>   using stunnel. Stunnel provides an encryption wrapper between a remote
>   client and a local (inetd-startable) or remote server, using the
>   OpenSSL library for cryptography. n To disable SSLv3 on stunnel, use
>   the following configuration parameters in the stunnel.conf file:

```
options = NO_SSLv2
options = NO_SSLv3
```

Comment: That would mean allowing non-encrypted connections on the SVN server, which we can't really do... Oh, well...

Comment: Communication between local stunnel and SVN server is still encrypted. It's not SSLv3 anymore, it should fall back to TLS.

Answer (score 0):

One solution was to recompile Subversion to use the new version of serf (1.3.8) -- the newest serf does not use SSLv3 either and so can talk to the TLS-only server. However, updating `svn`-client on dozens of systems is problematic in its own right.

We solved this problem by modifying Apache on the server as described in [my answer to my own question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/640344/why-did-git-stop-working-after-server-disabled-sslv3). Best of luck.